# Swift Moving Objects with Duration

Tags: swift

I'm making a game which involves a circle moving down slowly from the top. I want to know how to make the circle move with duration down. I've researched a few things such as beizer paths and animation, but the code never seems to really work when I try it. If you can do a sample code on how I can achieve something to move from top to bottom, that will be great! However, I know many people on stackoverflow do not prefer to write entire lines of code, so it would also be okay if you simply give me some guide as to what to research. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to animate a circle down from the top, look into the `UIView` class methods for animation. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW108) is the official class reference for UIView animations and [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76200/basic-uiview-animation-swift-tutorial) is one simple starter tutorial. If you're looking to make the view drop dynamically, realistically (e.g. like gravity) or via user interaction then I would look into the `UIDynamicaAnimator` class, referenced [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDynamicAnimator_Class/index.html) in the official documentation. [Here's](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/uidynamics-in-swift/) a starter tutorial on dynamic animations and behaviors and [here's](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76147/uikit-dynamics-tutorial-swift) a second tutorial.